# Actualizar Jtable despues de Insertar un Dato a la Base de Datos

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un problema al querer actualizar un Jtable , al momento de dar click al boton de insertar deberia de aparecer en el jtable el dato ingresado pero no me aparece nada

esto que lo que tengo en el boton insertar Detalle:

```
insertar ins = new insertar();  
ins.insdetfactcompra(Integer.parseInt(txtFactura.getText()),txtDescripcion.getText(),Float.parseFloat(txtPrecio.getText()));
float precio = Float.parseFloat(txtPrecio.getText());
txtDescripcion.setText("sin descripcion");
txtPrecio.setText("0.00");  
total = total + precio;
txtTotal.setText(Float.toString(total));
modeloTabla.setRowCount(0);   

try{
    String sql = "Select descripcion,precio from detalle_factura_compra where factura="+Integer.parseInt(txtFactura.getText());
    PreparedStatement ps = con.conexion().prepareStatement(sql);
    try (ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery()) {
        Object datos[]= new Object[2];
        while(res.next()){
            for (int i = 0;i<2;i++){
                datos[i]= res.getObject(i+1);
            }
            modeloTabla.addRow(datos);
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Consulta_Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al momento de hacer un insert a un jTable, el dato ingresado no se mostrara al momento, lo que puedes hacer es crear un metodo que haga un select a la tabla que ingresaste el dato apuntando al jtable, asi, podras hacer como un refresh a la tabla, osea asi:

[
CODIGO DE TU INSERT
]

[
LLAMAS AL METODO
]

Y listo :3, espero tu feedback

Comment: gracias si me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Solucion

```
public class Registro_Factura_Compra extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    float total = 0;
    int factura_detalle=0;
    conectar con = new conectar();
    Connection cc = con.conexion();
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable tabla = new JTable(modelo);
public Registro_Factura_Compra() {


    initComponents();        
}
//clase que llamo para llenar la tabla despues de insertar datos
private void LLenarTabla(int fd){
    modelo.addColumn("descripcion");
    modelo.addColumn("precio");
    modelo.setRowCount(0);

        try {
            Statement s = cc.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT descripcion,precio FROM sgc_contabilidad.detalle_factura_compra where factura="+fd);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                // Se crea un array que será una de las filas de la tabla.
                Object [] fila = new Object[2]; // Hay tres columnas en la tabla

                // Se rellena cada posición del array con una de las columnas de la tabla en base de datos.
                for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
                fila[i] = rs.getObject(i+1); // El primer indice en rs es el 1, no el cero, por eso se suma 1.

                // Se añade al modelo la fila completa.
                modelo.addRow(fila);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Registro_Factura_Compra.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}

//boton con el que inserto datos

private void btnRDetalleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    insertar ins = new insertar();    

    ins.insdetfactcompra(factura_detalle,txtDescripcion.getText(),Float.parseFloat(txtPrecio.getText()));
    float precio = Float.parseFloat(txtPrecio.getText());
    txtDescripcion.setText("sin descripcion");
    txtPrecio.setText("0.00");  
    total = total + precio;
    txtTotal.setText(Float.toString(total));

    LLenarTabla(factura_detalle);

}
```

en propiedades del jtable en model -> custom code -> [nombre del modelo asignado]